# functionals of Dirichlet process mixture

Tags: dirichlet-process

I want to solve (or simulate) `/int f(x)G(dx)` where f is a function(or phrase of x) and G is DPM(Dirichlet Process mixture prior). Muliere (1998) approximate this integral when G is DP, I dont know to approximate it when G is DPM. I can write it also

```
/int f dG = E_{G}(f(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

A pretty classical reference is:

[Markov Chain Sampling Methods for Dirichlet Process Mixture Models - Neal](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/npbayes/papers/neal_sampling.pdf)

which can be adapted to calculating such integrals using MCMC.